# Obtain user credentials "password" from AccountManager

Tags: android

Is there a way to get Gmail user account's password by overcoming the SecurityException.

I am working on sending emails in the background without user prompt. The javamail API I used for this requires username and password of the account from which emails should be sent. I am finding trouble to get a Password using AccountManger in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, no. The `ActivityManager.getPassword()` call is only allowed to applications that have the same UID as the authenticator module (in this case Google applications). Even if you managed to call it though, it doesn't store the actual password but an encrypted version of it, or a master token. You can find more details about how it works here: http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/11/android-online-account-management.html

Google's SMTP servers do support OAuth2 tokens in place of password though, so you can just get a token from `AccountManager` and use it to authenticate and send email. Details here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

Comment: Thanx :)  For the option you suggested of Google SMTP Servers which support tokens instead of password , I tried one poc & got the token from Account manager & passed as a parameter. However it gives me exceeption javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException showing Invalid credentials. Please guide me through getting the right token.

Comment: Refer to the documentation linked in the answer.